# par(xpd) does not clip barplots?

Tags: r, clipping

Clipping does not seem to affect `barplot()` -- ??

```
par(xpd=F); barplot(1:60, ylim=c(0,6)); segments(0,0,200,100, lwd=5)
```

The line segment is clipped at `y=6`, but the barplot goes to the top of the page!
I just upgraded (Fire Safety, 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) on a mac); I tried using the quartz device and also using a pdf device -- same error.  Works fine if I use `plot()` instead of `barplot()`.

Does anyone else have this error?  Any explanations or workarounds?

Thanks!

larry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`barplot` has an `xpd` argument, which is overriding the setting in `par`. From `?graphics::barplot`

> ```
> ## Default S3 method:
> barplot(height, width = 1, space = NULL,
>         names.arg = NULL, legend.text = NULL, beside = FALSE,
>         horiz = FALSE, density = NULL, angle = 45,
>         col = NULL, border = par("fg"),
>         main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL,
>         xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, xpd = TRUE, log = "",
>         axes = TRUE, axisnames = TRUE,
>         cex.axis = par("cex.axis"), cex.names = par("cex.axis"),
>         inside = TRUE, plot = TRUE, axis.lty = 0, offset = 0,
>         add = FALSE, args.legend = NULL, ...)
> ```
>
> ....
>
> ```
> xpd: logical. Should bars be allowed to go outside region?
> ```

This works, for example,

```
barplot(1:60, ylim=c(0,6), xpd = FALSE)
```